# How to dynamically add a user type form to a user profile form in django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am a beginner user to django and I have created a custom user model. I am using the crispy form helper to create my forms. I have a standard user form that requires the user to select a user_type for validation. How do I bind the user_type to the user and render a new form based off the user_type selection and save/post the data. Or is there a better or simpler way to achieve the same outcome. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (User_Type1, 'is_usertype1'),
        (User_Type2, 'is_usertype2'),
        (User_Type3, 'is_usertype3'),
        (User_Type4, 'is_usertype4'),
        (User_Type5, 'is_usertype5'),
        (User_Type6, 'is_usertype6'),
        (User_Type7, 'is_usertype7'),
        (Superuser, 'is_superuser'),
        )
    user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    is_director = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype5= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype6 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_usertype7 = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    password_2 = models.CharField(_('password_2'), max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='please enter your first name', null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='please enter your last name', null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(UserType, default='User_Type1', choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    professional_title = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='please enter your professional title', null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='description default text', blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**example User_type model**

```
class User_Type1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=False, unique=True)
    is_usertype1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    is_director =  models.BooleanField(User)
    #projects = models.ManyToOneField('projects.Project', related_name='+')
    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='architect_profile_image', blank=True)
    phone = models.FloatField(max_length=12, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='please enter your address', null=True)
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    linkedIn = models.URLField(default='')
    instagram = models.URLField(default='')
    facebook = models.URLField(default='')
    licence_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='please enter your licence number', null=True)
    insurance = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='please enter your insurance details', null=True)
    insurance_2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='please enter your address', null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_type1'
```

**forms.py**

```
    class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
        class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = (
                    'email',
                    'password',
                    'password_2',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'date_of_birth',
                    'professional_title',
                    'bio',
                    #'user_type', 
                    #'is_active'
                    )
        
            def form_valid(self, form):
                pass
        
        
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.helper = FormHelper(self)
                self.helper.form_tag = False
                self.helper.labels_uppercase = True
                self.helper.form_id = 'id-EditProfileForm'
                self.helper.form = 'EditProfileForm'
                self.helper.form_class = 'EditProfileForm'
                self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
                self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-12'
                self.helper.layout = Layout(
                    Div(
                        Div(
                            HTML("""
                                <p><b>Edit Profile</b></p>
                                """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        
                        Div(
                            Div(Field ('email', placeholder='Email', css_class="controls col-md-12 col-lg-6",), css_class='col-md-12',),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(HTML("""
                            <br>
                            """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(
                            Div(Field ('password', placeholder='Password', css_class="controls col-md-12 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-12',),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(HTML("""
                            <br>
                            """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(
                            Div(Field ('password_2', placeholder='Password_2', css_class="controls col-md-12 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-12',),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(HTML("""
                            <br>
                            """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(
                            Div(Field ('first_name', placeholder='First Name', css_class="controls col-md-6 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-6',),
                            Div(Field ('last_name', placeholder='Last Name', css_class="controls col-md-6 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-6',),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(HTML("""
                            <br>
                            """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ), 
                        Div(
                            Div(Field ('date_of_birth', placeholder='Date of Birth', css_class="controls col-md-6 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-6',),
                            Div(Field ('professional_title', placeholder='Profossional Title', css_class="controls col-md-6 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-6',),
                            css_class='row' 
                            ),
                        Div(HTML("""
                            <br>
                            """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(
                            Div(Field ('bio', placeholder='Please enter a short bio about yourself', css_class="controls col-md-12 col-lg-12",), css_class='col-md-12',),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
                        Div(HTML("""
                            <br>
                            """),
                            css_class='row'
                            ),
        
                        Div(
                            ButtonHolder(
                                Submit('submit', 'Save Profile', css_class='button white'),
                                ),
                            ),
                        css_class='controls col-md-12',
                        ))
                self.render_required_fields = True



class UserType1Form(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
            model = UserType1
            fields = (
                'user',
                'is_usertype1',
                'is_director',
                'image',
                'phone',
                'address',
                'website',
                'linkedIn',
                'instagram',
                'facebook',
                'licence_number', 
                'insurance',
                'insurance_2',
                'date_created',
                )

        def form_valid(self, form):
            pass


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserType1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper(self)
            self.helper.form_tag = False
            self.helper.labels_uppercase = True
            self.helper.form_id = 'id-UserType1Form'
            self.helper.form = 'UserType1Form'
            self.helper.form_class = 'UserType1Form'
            self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
            self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-12'
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                
                )
            self.render_required_fields = True
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url = 'account_login')
def user_profile_edit(request):
     u_form = EditUserForm(instance=request.user)
     ut1_form = UserType1Form(instance=request.user.profile)
     title = 'Profile Page'
     template_name = 'profile.html'
     context = {
         'title': title,
         'u_form': u_form,
         'ut1_form': ut1_form
     }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_class = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None)
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg))
        if form.is_valid():
            email = (form.cleaned_data['email'])
            password = (form.cleaned_data['password'])
            password_2 = (form.cleaned_data['password_2'])
            first_name = (form.cleaned_data['first_name'])
            last_name = (form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
            date_of_birth = (form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'])
            user_type = (form.cleaned_data['user_type'])
            professional_title = (form.cleaned_data['professional_title'])
            bio = (form.cleaned_data['bio'])

            ### Do I add Usertype 1 -6 form data here? ###

            update_info = form.save(commit=False)
            update_info.user = request.user
            update_info.save()
            formset = EditProfileForm()
            helper = EditProfileForm()
            form = super(form, self).get_form(form_class)
            form.helper = FormHelper()
            form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create', css_class='btn-primary'))
            profile.user = request.user
            instance = form.save()

            if redirect_url is not None:
                form.helper.form_action = reverse('save_profile') + redirect_url

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request,'profile.html', {'form': form, 'helper': helper})

        else:
            print (form.errors)
            form = 'EditProfileForm'
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm()
        helper = EditProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'profileedit.html', {'form': form, 'helper': helper})
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your problem is? What have you tried? What is the error?

Comment: since you asked for a simpler way.. you could remove all the boolean fields `is_user_type_1` and so on.. they contain redundant information and that can lead to errors and confusion. If I understand it correctly you want to assign just one user type to the user(?)

Comment: Do you want to have one view with one form to edit the user and the user_type at the same time? In that case you have to think about how you want to modify the form/views when the user switches the user_type or is that not possible?

Comment: Hi Opsse and @sarbot, I am trying assign one user_type to a user, with the option to change to another user_type at a later date. I'd prefer to keep it as simple as possible as I am still trying to get my head around understanding the django process. I dont mind how its done, but a user should be able to change their user_type and only have access to the selected user type form. I know I will have to have several user_type forms for the various user types, but they should only be able to access their selected user_type form, if you get what I mean.